# Right to Left in react-native

Tags: react-native, native-base

By using this code(in below),The App has been RTL but location of Right & Left changed(So things must be shown in Right are turned to Left).I did it via [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps.html).

```
ReactNative.I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
```

And another problem is when Mobile's language is LTR, Location of Images & designs turns into another side(for e.g changes from Right to Left) because App has only one LTR language. Is there any way for showing RTL & LTR like each other??

Comment: Hi Mohammad, were you able to learn more about this situation? I have similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use this code :

first :

```
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native';
```

second in the App class use this :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
}
```

something like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, I18nManager } from 'react-native';
import { Header } from './src/components/common';
import LoginForm from './src/components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header headerText="Authentication" />
        <LoginForm />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: That's awesome!. Thanks. But, it's working on IOS not Android. Could you explain?