# change style react native material dropdown

Tags: react-native

native-material-dropdown`, I want to create this dropdown in the picture below:
[image]

but the arrow in the left :
[image]
 how can I change this to left? this my code below :

```
  < Dropdown
        renderAccessory={() => (
          <Image resizeMode="contain" source={combo_arrow_icon} style={{ marginTop: 5, justifyContent: 'center', }}/>
        )}
        inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'transparent' }}
        onChangeText={(value) => props.newHandelChange(value)}
        dropdownMargins={{ min: 15, max: 15 }}
        dropdownOffset={{ top: 10, left: 0 }}
        dropdownPosition={- 5}
        style={{ marginTop: 5, fontWeight: 'bold', fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile', fontSize: 16, textAlign: 'right', }}
        itemTextStyle={{ textAlign: 'center', fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile' }}
        absoluteRTLLayout={false}
        containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#59c5b8', borderWidth: 0.5, borderRadius: 1, marginLeft: 16, marginRight: 16, marginBottom: 8, fontSize: 18, fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile' }}
        data={props.data ? props.data : dataGroup}
        placeholder="(پیش فرض گروه فعال)..."
        placeholderTextColor='#000'
        placeholderStyle={{ fontWeight: '200', fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile', }}
      />
```

Comment: I think it because the language is work as RTL layout, so it goes to different side, maybe you could try `absoluteRTLLayout={true}`?

Comment: I set absoluteRTLLayout={true} but nothing change.@高鵬翔

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two option for handling that,

1.you need to make the layout of your app RTL so everything will be handled automatically For more info =>>

---https://reactnative.dev/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps

---[Right to Left in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191621/right-to-left-in-react-native)

2. you need too change the Default Style of DropDown by going to `./node_module/react-native-material-dropdown/src/component/dropdown/styles.js` and do the following :
   import **Dimentions** from react native and add
   `const {width,height}=Dimensions.get('window')` then go to the **accessory** style and add `right:width*.94` to the end ,
   by doing this you will be able to have some result like:
   [image]

Comment: thank for the answer but in `./node_module/react-native-material-dropdown/src/component` have two folder `dropdown` and `item` and both have style.which one, and for the first way when I18nManager all icon change and not good!

Comment: its under dropdown folder

Comment: if it helped you, please upvote and mark as answer so when any one have the same problem they can figure the answer , thanks, happy coding <3  @AmirFarahani

Comment: I change this but nothing to change?` accessory: {
    right:width*.94,
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },`@Amir Doreh

Comment: added this `right:width*.94` to style my custom icon and ok, thanks a lot <3